# Can anyone explain this npm package.json script usage?

Tags: node.js, npm, package.json

I have some really old code I am going through and am having trouble finding an explanation online for why it is no longer working.  The node version we were probably on predates 16.x, we were using [cross-conf-env](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cross-conf-env)@1.1.2 and [env-cmd](https://www.npmjs.com/package/env-cmd)@5.1.0.

In our package.json we had scripts like this:

```
{
  "name": "my-package",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "cross-conf-env env-cmd npm_package_config_target webpack ...",
    "start": "npm run build --my-package:target=development && <start cmd>",
  } 
}
```

My question is about the start script.  It seemed like what we were doing here was somehow configuring a value that **cross-conf-env** could then replace.  But from what I've read about **cross-conf-env** it really is only reading from values in your **package.json** or environment variables but we, in the past, never had any set.  It seemed as if it was always set via an npm run argument.  e.g. "--my-package:target=development"

For now I've just removed the usage of cross-conf-env since it was only being used to have a single build script to modify instead of one per environment.

Any knowledge of this usage would be helpful.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the start script in your package.json using cross-conf-env to configure a value for the build, specifically the npm_package_config_target variable, which would then be used by env-cmd to set the environment before running the build with webpack.
So basically, when you run npm run start, it triggers the start script. which in turn runs the build script. The build script uses cross-conf-env to set a temporary value for the npm_package_config_target variable, which is specific to the build process. The env-cmd package reads the temporary value for npm_package_config_target set by cross-conf-env and uses it to set the appropriate environment for the build process. Development environment for example. The build process, which includes webpack, runs with the environment configuration set by env-cmd.

Comment: I am not sure this answers my question of how or what was allowing "--my-package:target=development" to be passed in when you run "npm run build --my-package:target=development" and then letting cross-conf-env do the replace for "npm_package_config_target" as "development".  It neither existed as an environment variable on the host machine or in the packge.json at $.config.target.  The documentation for cross-conf-env also doesn't indicate how/what would have allowed this to work.